# Auto-import VueJs components while coding at SublimeText

Tags: vue.js, sublimetext, auto-import

Is there a way to auto import a VueJs component inside another while I'm coding at SublimeText 3?

For instance, imagine I have a `MyComponent.vue` file:

```
<template>
  <page-header
    :title="$t('title')"
    :count="playerSelector.total"
    :subtitle="$t('subtitle', playerSelector.total)"
    hide-search
  >
  ...
</template>
<script>
import PageHeader from '@/lib/components/PageHeader'; // automatically add this line

export default {
  name: 'MyComponent',
  ...
```

In the example, I have a component `MyComponent` that imports another custom component `<page-header>`...so I wanted to know how to add the import statement `import PageHeader from '@/lib/components/PageHeader';` without actually typing it every time.

I've tried installing `ImportJs` and `AutoImport` plugins for Sublime, but for my understanding they only work for `.js` or `.ts` files. Is there a way to do that but for `.vue` files?

Answer (score 0):

Select **`Tools → Developer → New Snippet…`** and change its content to the following:

```xml
<snippet>
    <content><![CDATA[
import PageHeader from '@/lib/components/PageHeader'
]]></content>
    <!-- Optional: Set a tabTrigger to define how to trigger the snippet -->
    <tabTrigger>iph</tabTrigger>
    <!-- Optional: Set a scope to limit where the snippet will trigger -->
    <scope>source.javascript, text.html.vue</scope>
</snippet>
```

Hit <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> (<kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>S</kbd> on Mac) to save, which will automatically open up in your `Packages/User` folder. The `Packages` directory is the one opened when selecting **`Preferences → Browse Packages…`**:

- Linux: `~/.config/sublime-text-3/Packages`
- OS X: `~/Library/Application Support/Sublime Text 3/Packages`
- Windows Regular Install: `C:\Users\YourUserName\AppData\Roaming\Sublime Text 3\Packages`
- Windows Portable Install: `InstallationFolder\Sublime Text 3\Data\Packages`

Save the file as `iph.sublime-snippet`, and that's it. Now, when you're editing a `.vue` file (assuming you're using a Vue syntax highlighting plugin like [`Vue Syntax Highlight`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Vue%20Syntax%20Highlight)), type in `iph` and hit <kbd>Tab</kbd>, and the snippet will be inserted. See [here](https://docs.sublimetext.io/guide/extensibility/snippets.html) for more information about snippets in Sublime Text.

---

## **EDIT**

I now have a better idea of what you want - autocomplete for installed Vue components. In that case, check out the Language Server Protocol [`LSP-vue`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP-vue) plugin, which also requires the [`LSP`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/LSP) plugin and [`Vue Syntax Highlight`](https://packagecontrol.io/packages/Vue%20Syntax%20Highlight) as well. Once you have everything set up properly (make sure you read *all* the docs!), you should have access to autocomplete, linting, code formatting, code navigation, and more.

Comment: Nice! But that only applies to the specified component, in the example "PageHeader", is that correct? I was lookin to a way that I could import any component into another without typing. Like an component auto-complete/auto-import.

Comment: @ArthurBorba please see my edited answer above. LSP and LSP-vue should do the trick.

Comment: Well, I might be getting there...I've installed all the plugins, and now when I start typing "import...." I get this at sublime's panel: "Vetur error 'import ... =' can only be used in TypeScript files". I'm searching about it but it's going really deep into another stuff. I'm currently working with Vue2, Vue-Cli and I'm not using Typescript in this project.